# Data Table is not showing correct result in Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, datatable

I want to use data table in my angular 4 application. I installed all that required data table files. You can see my

> package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.6"
  }
```

I included the JS and CSS files in Angular CLI

> angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
      ],
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
```

In the component.html file, I have used the table tag.

```
<table datatable id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

In the component.ts file, `import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';` is already imported. And in app.module import and export for that module is ok.

Result:
I am getting the data table, yes, but the sorting is not working, the table displays all the record on the single page, which means pagination is not working. Table export is also not working.

I tried different techniques in component.ts file to make it working. like I add that code

```
ngOnInit() {
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
 } );
}
```

But unfortunately, nothing is work for me. Please help me how to fix that.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: Yes I checked that, I can not see any error. I also checked with https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started who has that module but did not got any solution